# Browser is putting in a p tag and ignoring my span

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is my code in the php file. excontent is an array, $rebuild is a string.

```
<div class="about-hero">
<h2><span class="accel"><?php echo $excontent[0] . " "; ?></span><?php echo $rebuild; ?> </h2>
</div>
```

This is what I get when I inspect the element:

```
    <div class="about-hero">
      <h2>
         <span class="accel">
            <p>
               "Accelerate is a marketing agency located in NYC.&nbsp;A great blah blah blah."
            </p>
         </span>
     </h2>  
   </div>
```

Any ideas why its putting in a p tag??? Its something with the PHP and I'm new to PHP. I tried it with just strings and it works fine. I'm changing the color of the first word in a sentence (following the design) the rebuild is the rest of the sentence. They both echo fine on their own and show the correct content.

Comment: "Any ideas why its putting in a p tag" — Presumably because you have one in `$excontent[0]`

Comment: You can use `var_dump($excontent);` to print all your array content.

Comment: `var_dump($excontent);` did not work to show the p tags the browser applied them. I found the p tags with `$new_string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $content);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the `<p>` tag is on the `$excontent[0]` variable. In this case, you could try removing all HTML tags from it:

```
<div class="about-hero">
<h2><span class="accel"><?php echo strip_tags($excontent[0]) . " "; ?></span><?php echo $rebuild; ?> </h2>
</div>
```

Or removing just the trailing and leading `<p>` and `</p>`:

```
<div class="about-hero">
<h2><span class="accel"><?php echo substr(trim(substr(trim($excontent[0]), 3, strlen($excontent[0]))), 0, -4) . " "; ?></span><?php echo $rebuild; ?> </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Do notice that `strip_tags()` remove most of HTML tags. I believe that the best approach is to find who is populating the array with the `<p>`

Comment: The OP really could tell us where `$excontent`'s comes from. If that text comes from some WYSIWYG Javascript HTML editor, they usually put that `<p>` tag.

Comment: The `substr()` approach is worse since there is no guarantee that  `<p>`is at the first 3 positions

Comment: I've trimmed the string now. Let's see what the OP will say about `$excontent`.

Comment: used `strip_tags()` the problem was  p tags. I'm new to this and echoing just applied the p tags I guess. I thought `$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );`  would handle this for me.. lots to learn about WP. I found the p tags with `$new_string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $content);`  $content was the string before I exploded it to work with the words in the string... Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your Browser will not "put" something into your HTML without any reason.

The first result of the Array is the place you should look at. You didn't provided your PHP Code, but im sure that result is where you find the `<p>` Tag ...

Just try this in JavaScript:

```
alert(<?PHP echo $excontent[0]; ?>);
```